# Render nav after login

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, aws-amplify

I am working on the react project. Currently, I am struggling to render the nav again after sign in to show the links that are only visible for logged in users. The following code works fine, and also the redirect goes to "/".

**The main issue is that the links for logged-in users only visible after a reload of the page.**

Nav.js

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {Nav, Navbar} from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify'
import SignIn from "./Authentication/SignIn";
import SignUp from "./Authentication/SignUp";
import SignOut from "./Authentication/SignOut";
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    withRouter,
    Redirect,
    Switch,
    Route,
    Link
} from "react-router-dom";

import Share from "./Share";
import Subscribe from "./Subscribe";
import Home from "./Home"

class PrivateRoute extends React.Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loaded: false,
            isAuthenticated: false
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.authenticate()
        this.unlisten = this.props.history.listen(() => {
            Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
                .then(user => console.log('user: ', user))
                .catch(() => {
                    if (this.state.isAuthenticated) this.setState({ isAuthenticated: false })
                })
            });
        }

        componentWillUnmount() {
            this.unlisten()
        }

        authenticate() {
        Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
            .then(() => {
                this.setState({ loaded: true, isAuthenticated: true});
            })
            .catch(() => this.props.history.push('/signup'))
        }

    render() {
        const { component: Component, ...rest } = this.props
        const { loaded , isAuthenticated} = this.state
        if (!loaded) return null
        return (
            <Route
                {...rest}
                render={props => {
                    return isAuthenticated ? (
                        <Component {...props} />
                    ) : (
                        <Redirect
                            to={{
                                pathname: "/signup",
                            }}
                        />
                    )
                }}
            />
        )
    }
}

PrivateRoute = withRouter(PrivateRoute)

class Routes extends React.Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showItemInMenu: false
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
         Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
                .then(() => { this.setState({showItemInMenu: true })})
                .catch(() => { this.setState({showItemInMenu: false})});
        }

    render() {
        const showItemInMenu = this.state.showItemInMenu
        return (

            <Router>
                <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
                    <Navbar.Brand as={Link} to="/">Todo</Navbar.Brand>
                    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav"/>
                    <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                        <Nav className="ml-auto">
                            <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/">Home</Nav.Link>
                            {showItemInMenu &&  <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/share" >Share</Nav.Link>}
                            {showItemInMenu &&  <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/subscribe" >Subscribe</Nav.Link> }
                            {showItemInMenu &&  <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/signout" >Logout</Nav.Link> }
                            <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/signup" >Registration</Nav.Link>
                            <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/signin" >Login</Nav.Link>
                        </Nav>
                    </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Navbar>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/'  component={Home}/>
                    <Route path='/signup' component={SignUp}/>
                    <Route path='/signin' component={SignIn}/>
                    <PrivateRoute path='/share' component={Share}/>
                    <PrivateRoute path='/subscribe' component={Subscribe}/>
                    <PrivateRoute path='/signout' component={SignOut}/>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}

export default Routes
```

Signin.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Form, Row, Col,Button, Alert,Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
class SignIn extends Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: '',
            password: '',
            message: '',
            redirect: false
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSignIn = this.handleSignIn.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange (event) {
        this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    }

    handleSignIn (event){
        event.preventDefault();

        const username = this.state.username;
        const password = this.state.password;
        // You can pass an object which has the username, password and validationData which is sent to a PreAuthentication Lambda trigger
        Auth.signIn({
            username,
            password
        })
            .then(user => console.log(user))
            .then(() => { this.setState({ redirect: true })
        })
            .catch(err =>
                this.setState({message: err.message})
            );

    };

    renderRedirect = () => {
        if (this.state.redirect) {
            return <Redirect
                to={{
                    pathname: "/",
                    state: { fromlogin: true }
                }}
            />

        }
    }

    render () {
        const Title = styled.div`
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
        `;

        return (
            <Container>
            <Row>
                <Col md={6}>
                    <Title>
                        <h3>Login Form</h3>
                    </Title>
                    <Form onSubmit={this.handleSignIn}>
                        <Form.Group>
                            <Form.Control type="text" name="username"  placeholder="Username" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Form.Group>
                            <Form.Control type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Form.Group>
                            <Button
                                variant="primary"
                                type="submit"
                                value="SIGN IN"
                            >LOGIN</Button>
                        </Form.Group>
                    </Form>

                    {this.state.message ?
                        <Alert variant="danger">{this.state.message}</Alert>
                        : <></>}
                </Col>
            </Row>
                {this.renderRedirect()}
            </Container>

        );
    }
}

export default SignIn
```

Comment: You need to add shared state (Like using redux, or contexts), so that when the authenticated user changes, it will rerender your components. (Right now you're only checking when the components mount, and never checking again)

Comment: @FrankerZ - I guess, you are right but I would like to avoid the complexity of setting up flux or redux. Let's if someone has an easier solution.

Comment: It's either flux/redux, or using contexts (Like I mentioned): https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: @meck373 Did you find a solution, I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @AzherAleem -  I used Redux to manage the state of this project but I would recommend to use reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: @meck373 I have used context API to manage the state of user info, but whenever I refresh the state is lost. I have thought of using local storage to store and persist data globally but all in vain, any leads?

Comment: @AzherAleem What about read and write the data from the database? I can give you my takeaways: So first I tried redux to store the information. When I discovered usecontext and refactored the whole app to usecontext. Currently, I use firebase to read and write user data from the database

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using React JS context API and local storage for storing the required state globally so that it does not revert on refresh.

Scenario: A top navbar containing site title is to visible every time regardless of user being signed in or not. The username and a logout button to appear in the top navbar only for logged in users. A side menu bar visible only for signed in users.

Issue: The username only appears after a reload to the main page just like the links in the above question.

Solution:

1. Create a file to store user context

**UserContext.js**

```
let reducer = (user, newUser) => {
    if (newUser === null) {
      localStorage.removeItem("user");
      return newUser;
    }
    return { ...user, ...newUser };
  };
  
  const userState = {
    name: "",
    email: "",
  };

const localState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
const AuthContext = createContext();

const AuthProvider = (props) =>{
    const [user, setUser] = useReducer(reducer, localState || userState);
  
    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
      }, [user]);
      
    return(
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
            {props.children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

export { AuthContext, AuthProvider };
```

2. Now in your App.js file wrap this AuthProvider over the components where user context is intended to be accessed.

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  return (
   
    <AuthProvider>
      <Router>
        <NavBar />
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/signin" exact component={SignIn} />           
            <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />  
            <ProtectedRoute path="/home" component={Home} /> 
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </AuthProvider>
    
  );
}
```

3. Now consume the context in the components that were wrapped with the context like the Home and Navbar component.

**NavBar.js**

```
export default function MiniDrawer() {
  const {user, setUser} = useContext(AuthContext)
  
  //set user context and local/global storage respective value to null on signout
  const handleSignOut = async () =>
  {
      try
      {
        await Auth.signOut()
        localStorage.removeItem("user");
        setUser(null)
        history.push("/signin")
      }catch(err)
      {
        console.log(err.message)
        alert('Could not sign out due to: ', err.message)
      }
  }

return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar
        position="fixed"
        className={clsx(classes.appBar, {
          [classes.appBarShift]: open,
        })}
      >
        <Toolbar>
          { user && user.name &&
              <IconButton
                color="inherit"
                aria-label="open drawer"
                onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
                edge="start"
                className={clsx(classes.menuButton, {
                  [classes.hide]: open,
                })}
              >
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
          }
          <Typography  variant="h6" noWrap>
            The Video Site  
          </Typography>
         
          { user && user.name && 
            <div className={classes.userArea}>
            <Typography >
              Welcome, {user && user.name}

            </Typography>  
            
              <ListItem button onClick={handleSignOut}> 
              <ListItemIcon>{<ExitToAppIcon /> }</ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary="Log out" />
              </ListItem>  
            </div>
          }
        </Toolbar>
            
      </AppBar>
      { user && user.name &&
          
      <Drawer
        variant="permanent"
        className={clsx(classes.drawer, {
          [classes.drawerOpen]: open,
          [classes.drawerClose]: !open,
        })}
        classes={{
          paper: clsx({
            [classes.drawerOpen]: open,
            [classes.drawerClose]: !open,
          }),
        }}
      >
        <div className={classes.toolbar}>
          <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
            {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <ChevronRightIcon /> : <ChevronLeftIcon />}
          </IconButton>
        </div>
        <Divider />
        <List>
            {
              SideBarData.map( (item) => {
                  return(
                      <Link to={item.path}>
                    <Tooltip title={item.title} aria-label="add">
                      <ListItem button key={item.title} >
                          <ListItemIcon>{item.icon}</ListItemIcon>
                          <ListItemText primary={item.title} />
                      </ListItem>
                      </Tooltip>
                    </Link>
                  )
                }
              )
            }
        </List>
        <Divider />        
      </Drawer>
      }
      <main className={classes.content}>
        <div className={classes.toolbar} />
        {/* <MediaUpload /> */}
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now, you have implemented context with local storage in order to maintain state even after refreshing.

Guidance [source](https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-cherry-thdsm?file=/src/Home.js:420-427)